# Function to expand div by time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I have a React Component where I am able to return the time in seconds as minutes from the JSON data and Moment.js. Here is how I am calling props:

`const [delayTailData, setDelayTailData] = useState(props.data);`

The data displays fine in minutes in the div when I do this.

From JSON file: `"delay": 900,` 
In Component: 15 (min)

Now I want to change state `useState(initialSize(props.data.delay));`  so that the two div classes `.tail` &  `.span` to increase in size of the divs as delay time increases.

#### DelayTailLbl.jsx

```
const DelayTailLbl = (props) => {

  const [delayWidth, setDelayWidth] = useState(initialSize(props.data.delay));
  console.log(props, 'delay');


  function initialSize(delay) {
    const originalSize = 50;
    const delayMinutes = parseInt(delay / 60);
    return delayMinutes === 0 ? originalSize : originalSize + delayMinutes;
    }

  return (
    <div>
      <div className={delayWidth > 300  ? style.tail : style.tailWarning}>
        <span className={style.span}>{moment.duration(delayWidth).asMinutes()}</span>

      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default DelayTailLbl;
```

Now, the `.span` div class is now not returning time correctly.

From JSON file: `"delay": 900,`
In Component: `0.0010833333333333333` (min)

I'm pretty new at this so I'm not able to figure out what I've done wrong here. Any ideas on how to fix it and more importantly, will this function work to expand the divs? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to show all those decimal , just show upto 2 decimal places

```
parseInt(delay / 60).toFixed(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Accoriding to [moment.js documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/creating/) you need to provide duration in milliseconds.
You can use:
`moment.duration(delayWidth, 'minutes');`
or
`moment.duration(delayWidth * 60 * 1000);`